# Issue with passing a filename as a parameter to a function?

Tags: php, string, user-defined-functions

I have this piece of code

```
redirect_loc(index.php);
```

And the definition for this function is somewhere in a functions file.

```
    function redirect_loc($location=NULL)
{
    if($location!=NULL)
    {
        header("Location:$location");
        exit;
    }
}
```

When I pass "index.php" (note the quotes around to specify as a string) it works, however passing index.php gives error The requested URL /indexphp was not found on this server.

Why doesn't this work when it's not passed as a string ?

Comment: What do you mean "not passed as a string"?  Can you give examples of the calling code, both one that works, and one that doesn't work?

Comment: I did provide the calling code, I'm not sure but has somebdy edited my question???

Comment: ok edited for the calling function, for some reason it wasn't there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The . acts as concatenation operator . Did you see what the name was of the file it couldn't find? No `.` ... It joined the two "strings" (`index` and `php`) together - it thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: ok , didn't realize the concatenation operator . functions even inside function parameters...

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
redirect_to(index.php);
```

This is taking `index` as a constant and `php` as another constant and concatenating them using the `.` concatenation operator.

It is looking for a constant named `index` (and again for one named `php`) and, not having found a constant with that name, uses the value "index" (or "php") as a string literal.

This is not recommended practice.  If you switch on error logging you will see that it is issuing a notice like "No constant defined `index`, assuming string value instead".

Comment: +1 Thanks for the additional info, I don't have error_logging working at the moment but I'll enable and see what it says...